# (a bit difficult) Find the volume of the region satisfying these conditions

Tags: calculus, analytic-geometry, volume

I trying to find the volume of the region in $R^3$ satisfying

$ 0 < \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \leq x^2+y^2 \leq z\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \leq 2 \sqrt{x^2+y^2} + y  $

Not even sure whether i should use cylindrical coordinate or spherical coordinate especially beacuse of the last inequality. I'm having a tough time, is there any help?

Comment: I think you should start by ignoring the expression involving $z$ temporarily, and figure out what the region in the $xy-$plane is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use cylindrical coordinates, I would say.  The conditions become $$
0<r\le r^2 \le zr \le 2r +r\cos\theta, $$or$$
1\le r \le z \le 2 +\cos\theta$$  Ignoring the expression with $z$ for the moment, we see that the solid in question lies above the region in the $xy-$plane outside the unit circle and inside the [limaçon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lima%C3%A7on) $ r=2+\cos\theta,$ so that the region to integrate over will be determined by the inequalities $$
0\le\theta\le2\pi,\ 1\le r \le 2+\cos\theta$$

You take it from here.